# Updating angularJS variables from javascript

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

I'm using an external autocomplete function that returns an object (not what is in the text input) and I want to use this object in angular. Right now I'm using the rootScope to do it:

```
function change(field, value) {
  var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=app]');
  var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      if (field) {
        $scope.partner = value;
      }
      else {
        $scope.keyword = value;
      }
    });

};
```

This works fine but I wanted to know if there is a cleaner way to interact with angular from the outside (like a set function). I'm pretty new to angular so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('mainController', function($rootScope, $routeParams, $location) {
    $rootScope.partner = {}
    $rootScope.partner.id = $routeParams.id;
    $rootScope.partner.name = $routeParams.name;
    $rootScope.keyword = $routeParams.keyword;
    updateFields($rootScope.partner.name, $rootScope.keyword);
    $rootScope.$watch('[partner,keyword]', function () { 
        $location.search('name', $rootScope.partner.name);
        $location.search('id', $rootScope.partner.id);
        $location.search('keyword', $rootScope.keyword);
     }, true);
});
```

It's not doing much for the moment, just using the queryparams in the url and updating them when the variable is changed by the autocomplete

Comment: would you post the controller?

Comment: yeah I'm assuming you are using an auto complete directive and will have to change the scope of this directive. However, without more info all I have are assumptions.

Comment: I added the controller.
The autocomplete is done in jquery.